# How to mock patch the Serializer.is_valid() method when unit testing in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I want to be able to unit test a view without connecting to the db, i can mock patch the User.save() method but a don't know how to patch serializer.is_valid() properly. It looks like is_valid method requires db connection to validate fields or something like that. Is there a way we can do this?

I'm using django-pytest and pytest-mock

here is the view a want to test

```py
class RegistrationViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        user = request.data.get('user', {})
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

here is my serializer

```py
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers registration request and creates a new user."""

    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True   # can not be read by the client
    )
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'token']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Here is my view test so far

```py
class TestRegistrationViewSet:
    """
    Test cases for registrating user
    """

    def test_register_user_success(self, rf, mocker):
        url = reverse('registration-list')
        data = {
            "user": {
                'username': 'user1',
                'email': "email@cookie.com",
                'password': 'user1pass'
            }
        }
        request = rf.post(url, data=data, content_type='application/json')

        mocker.patch.object(User, 'save')
        response = RegistrationViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'})(request).render()
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

This is the error traceback i'm getting

```py
repostery\authentication\views.py:21: in create
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py:234: in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py:433: in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py:490: in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py:830: in run_validation
    return super().run_validation(data)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py:566: in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py:588: in run_validators
    validator(value, self)
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\validators.py:73: in __call__
    if qs_exists(queryset):
.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\validators.py:21: in qs_exists
    return queryset.exists()
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:777: in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py:538: in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py:1121: in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py:1149: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py:26: in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py:260: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.backends.postgresql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x00000218938FA670>, name = None

    def _cursor(self, name=None):
>       self.ensure_connection()
E       RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.

.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py:236: RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're testing is the `is_valid()` method you should patch the part of the method that's intended to access the db for the test not to become to expensive (since accessing the db takes time and resources). For example, here I tested that my serializer raise the proper errors when fields were missing:

```
mocker.patch('rest_framework.validators.qs_exists', return_value=True)
        with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can try to add @pytest.mark.django_db to the test or you can patch the method you mentioned like this:
`mocker.patch("project.views.RegistrationSerializer.is_valid")`

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is:

```py
with patch('rest_framework.views.APIView.handle_exception') as mocked_object:
    response = self.client.post(self.url, data=data, format='json')
    mocked_object.assert_called_once()
```

When the serializer raises an exception, it is handled by rest_framework and the users only get an HTTP 400.
However, I recommend not using this solution because it is tied to the current implementation of DRF and we're not guaranteed that it will stay the same.